# How can I get RMSE from training data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, metrics, training-data

I have a problem. I found this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56302/what-are-good-rmse-values

Someone wrote:

> The RMSE for your training and your test sets should be very similar
> if you have built a good model.

and another wrote:

> RMSE of test > RMSE of train => OVER FITTING of the data. RMSE of test
> < RMSE of train => UNDER FITTING of the data.

I think RMSE of test data it is

```
y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
rmse = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred , squared=False)
```

But how could I get the RMSE (or another metric) of my training data? Perhaps it is

```
rmse = metrics.mean_squared_error(X_train, X_test, squared=False)
```

But with that I got

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [8880, 2220]
```

So how could I get the RMSE from my training ?

```py
from sklearn.neighbors import (KNeighborsRegressor,)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=30)
knn = KNeighborsRegressor(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski', metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=5,
    p=2, weights='uniform')
knn.fit(X, y)

y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
mse = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
rmse = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred , squared=False)
print(rmse)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's something wrong with your code and it's that you are training your model with the whole data, instead of the training data you've already split, this makes your validation sample useless as the model itself learnt from it.
You should change your fit like so:

```py
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Then to get the RMSE of it you should use the predict on your train data and compare it afterwards:

```py
y_train_pred = knn.predict(X_train)
rmse = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_train, y_train_pred, squared=False)
```

Everything else should stay the same

Answer (score -1):

The context of your question is not clear. However, you should take the predictions and not the model features of the test set, and evaluate the RMSE using the same package that you used:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html

Pay attention to the `squared` parameter.